# Finding orientation of a point with respect to another point in xy plane

Tags: math, geometry, point, direction, coordinate

I have a problem (and a solution too). What I want to know is how to arrive at "that" solution. "That" solution is perfect and working fine for all possible combinations.

Assume that you have 3 points in the XY coordinate system: `P1(x1, y1)`, `P2(x2, y2)` and `P3(x3, y3)`.

Now, join the point P2 with P3. It will result in "ray" originating from point P2 and passing through point P3. I used word *ray* because I want it in only one direction, i.e. from P2 to P3.

Now, with respect to point P1, is the *ray* `P2 --> P3` in a clockwise or counterclockwise direction?

---

Solution is:

> use following formulae to find value of z1:
>
> `z1 = (x3 - x1)(y2 - y1) - (y3 - y1)(x2 - x1)`
>
> If `z1` is positive, `P2 --> P3` is clockwise. If `z1` is negative, `P2 --> P3` is counterclockwise. And if it is 0 the points are on the same imaginary line extending from `P1`.

Can someone please help me how to arrive at this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you've written is very similar to the formula of **cross product** of two vectors. As the direction of the cross product is dependent on the CW/CCW configuration, you can easily use it for your problem.

You can construct two rays `P1->P2` and `P1->P3`. Then you can take their cross product. If the component of the product along Z-axis is positive, then P2 and P3 is in counterclockwise order, and vice versa.

If you try to do that, the result, which would be the coefficient of k (unit vector along Z-axis) in the cross product, will be precisely the same as the answer you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this works. I tried it, but it keeps giving me the same answer for both. 
Try these coordinates:

```
Start point 0, 90, 0
Center point 0, 0, 0
End point 90, 0, 0
.....
directional vector 1, 0, 0
inverse directional vector -1, 0, 0
```

Comment: Hi benhur, I am not sure how you provided (0, 90, 0) as a start point. My question is only for 2D(X-Y) co-ordinate system.